# Does anyone make a small locking enclosure for 19" switches?

Tags: networking, physical-security

Every once in a while I need to put a rack mount switch on a table for a few days for LAN access. Does any company make a locking enclosure for a single 1U switch? The smaller the better. Just something that will keep people from bumping fiber connections and messing with RJ45 connections.

Comment: Lock the door to the room, or put it somewhere it can't get bumped into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about Fly cases ?

You can get a small one like this one : 
http://www.woodbrass.com/flight+case+rack+4u+gator+gr4l ,

Close the front door to hide the switch, and pass the fibers and cables by the back.

It's standard 19" so it should not be a problem, I use this for my lab.

Comment: I didn't even think about these, the portability is a big plus. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Closest thing I can think of is something [like this 10U wall-mount rack.](http://www.startech.com/product/CAB1019WALL-10U-19inch-Wall-Mounted-Rack-Equipment-Cabinet)  (Np affiliation, I just buy some stuff from them occasionally.)  For this one, you'd have to bolt on some sort of back cover, but that could just be a piece of wood.

Try googling variations of "wall-mount 19 rack" or "desktop 19 rack"

Also try searching for "enclosures" not racks, that's how I found this one:

http://www.verotec.co.uk/news.php?id=11&osCsid=1ou8hr8u802uo2o06q995743v0

One last result that turned up searching for desktop 19" enclosures.  Never heard of this company before, but this looks like what you're after:

http://www.rackmountsolutions.net/Table_top_Server_Racks.asp

Comment: OTOH, isn't this a shopping question?

Answer (score 1):

Not endorsing any of these products or the supply company in particular, but it's a good reference for what is available: http://milestek.com/c-1451-small-system-wall-cabinets.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Such cabinets are extremely common. Where to get one will depend on just where you are, as it's unlikely to be cost effective to have them transported any great distance. I suggest you pop in to your local electrical wholesaler (or whatever they're called where you are) and pick the one you like from the many available makes and models.